# how to access pybind11::dict by key

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have following py binding in C++:

```
m.def("myf", [](const pybind11::dict &py_params) -> bool {
  // how can I access this pybind11::dict by key?
  // std::cout << py_params["item1"]["key1"] << '\n';  // Doesn't work
  return true;
}
```

I call this in python with:

```
myf({
  "item1": {
    "key1": "A",
    "key2": {
      "subkey1": "A1",
      "subkey2": "A2"
    }
  },
  "item2": {
    "key1": "B",
    "key2": {
      "subkey1": "B3",
      "subkey2": "B4"
    }
  }
})
```

**Question:**
How can I access this pybind11::dict by key?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed `.c_str()` for [], and `.cast<std::string>()` for cout

```
for (auto &item : py_params) {
    const std::string &item_name = item.first.cast<std::string>();
    std::string key1 = py_params[item_name.c_str()]["key1"].cast<std::string>();

    std::cout << item_name << '\n';
    std::cout << item1 << '\n';

    const pybind11::dict &key2 = py_params[item_name.c_str()]["key2"].cast<pybind11::dict>();
    for (auto &subkey : key2) {
        const std::string &sub_key = subkey.first.cast<std::string>();
        const std::string &sub_val = subkey.second.cast<std::string>();
        std::cout << sub_key << '\n';
        std::cout << sub_val << '\n';
    }
}
```